# Remove Default Content of the Listview in Android

Tags: android, listview

I am working on a android project where I need to display data in `ListView` dynamically using array.
Everything is working fine only the Default layout of the list is also coming in the list View which needs to be removed

this is main_activity.xml

```
 <com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayoutListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayoutListView>
```

This is my list_row.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#3399FF"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is My customAdaptor

```
   public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                                 List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtTitle;
        //TextView txtDesc;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
           // holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

       // holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is  Main.activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final String[] array = {"Hello", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome"};
private final Integer[] images ={R.drawable.milk , R.drawable.bread , R.drawable.egg,R.drawable.fruit};
public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Strawberry",
        "Banana", "Orange", "Mixed" };

public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
        "It is an aggregate accessory fruit",
        "It is the largest herbaceous flowering plant", "Citrus Fruit",
        "Mixed Fruits" };


ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    System.out.println("*******************************************");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
            R.layout.view_row, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

The output of the above code is :
[image]

The images and content are coming from an array .. but I am also getting default row at the start . How do I remove that default row and show only the data coming from Array

Comment: Have you set any header to your ListView?

Answer (score 0):

Your library uses this [layout](https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout/blob/master/library/src/main/res/layout/view_expandable.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_expandable_headerlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_expandable_contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_expandable_headerlayout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

you can set the visibility of `view_expandable_headerlayout` to `gone` or `invisible`.

Or you can set your own custom header by `el_headerLayout` from its [attr](https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout/blob/master/library/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ExpandableLayout">
        <attr name="el_headerLayout" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="el_contentLayout" format="reference" />
        <attr name="el_duration" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: thanks, fr replay but i didn't understand your answer can you elaborate your answer. the things which you are saying is already there

Comment: for example like you call `listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);` you can use `FrameLayout framelayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.listview);` and then call `framelayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`